# Сохранение настроек плагина Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-extension

Пишу плагин, который на текущей вкладке вызывает скрипт, который заполняет определенные поля (имя, телефон, адрес и т.п.).

Как сделать сохранение этих значений?

В идеале: забить их в каком-то файле (например, в `json`) и при запуске скрипта для вкладки вытаскивать их.

Цель – один раз заполнить поля, чтобы плагин их находил, главное, чтобы после перезапуска firefox'а они не потерлись.

Делаю для себя, но прописывать внутри кода эти значения не хочу – отсутствие гибкости и выкладывание личной информации.

Потом бы добавил к плагину простой интерфейс для заполнения тех полей.

Comment: Смотря для каких цели и какова стоит задача, настройки можно в ФФ да и вообще в браузерах, при помощи COOKIEs

Comment: поищите что-то про такое в ФФ about:config как туда можно записывать программно свои данные

Comment: Интересная идея, попробую поразбираться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть еще один способ хранить настройки плагинов: [simple-prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs)

Нужно в `package.json` добавить поле `preferences` и в него добавить свои параметры. После, эти параметры будут доступны в настройках плагина в `about:addons`. При изменении настройки сохраняются, включая между запусками браузера.

**UPDATE:**

Плагин работает!

[Исходник плагина](https://github.com/gil9red/filling_checkout_pizzagold/blob/master/index.js): создание кнопки плагина и заполнение полей.

Значения полей берутся из [настроек плагина](https://github.com/gil9red/filling_checkout_pizzagold/blob/master/package.json).

Answer (score 3):

[Simple Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage) – доступный только для расширений FireFox.

Пример использования:

```
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");
ss.storage.myArray = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13];
ss.storage.myBoolean = true;
ss.storage.myNull = null;
ss.storage.myNumber = 3.1337;
ss.storage.myObject = { a: "foo", b: { c: true }, d: null };
ss.storage.myString = "O frabjous day!";
```

И надо бы что-то придумать с шифрованием данных.